# Zend Framework 2 - PDF - load pdf template

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-pdf

when i want to load a pdf template i do get an error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ZendPdf\PdfDocument::getPageDictionary() in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/test/vendor/zendframework/zendpdf/library/ZendPdf/PdfDocument.php:516 ....

This is my code:

```
$pdf = new ZendPdf\PdfDocument();
$pdf->pages[] = ($page1 =  $pdf->load('public/agb.pdf'));
```

This code works fine:

```
$pdf = new ZendPdf\PdfDocument();
$pdf->pages[] = ($page1 = $pdf->newPage('A4'));
```

Does someone have an idea?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use \ZendPdf\Page method (getPageDictionary()) on \ZendPdf\PdfDocument object. $pdf->newPage() works fine because returns Page object.

Some code examples: Merging two pdf`s:

```
    $pdf = new \ZendPdf\PdfDocument('a.pdf', null, true);
    $pdf2 = new \ZendPdf\PdfDocument('b.pdf', null, true);

    foreach ($pdf2->pages as $page) {
        $pdf->pages[] = clone $page;
    }

    $pdf->save('a.pdf');
```

Adding new page to existing pdf:

```
 $pdf = new \ZendPdf\PdfDocument('public/agb.pdf', null, true);
 $pdf->pages[] = $pdf->newPage('A4'); 
 $pdf->save('public/agb.pdf');
```

Comment: For example I want to create a site with:

    $pdf = new ZendPdf\PdfDocument();
    $pdf->pages[] = ($page1 = $pdf->newPage('A4')); 

And then for example i want to add a second page, which is a saved pdf file. How can i do it?

Comment: Just edited my answer and left there some example code.